# How to send a .txt file using Python on a Discord Bot?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, discord, bots

sorry for the basic question I'm very much a beginner. As such I more need you to face me in the correct direction than do it for me.

I have a discord bot that's functional in JS, but in trying to run it 24/7 from a Raspberry Pi it's easier to just translate it to Python. The original JS code is functional and can respond to `!movies` and `!TV` with a list of what I have downloaded to watch, as a `.txt` file. I have a series of `.bat` files that regularly compile the lists and scp/ssh it to my Pi. So the `.txt` files are sitting on my Pi. I can get the Python version to respond to `!movies` with a text reply but can't figure out sending a local `.txt` file. Any guide I can find is based around `.txt` files created by the code. All I need help on is making the send function send a `.txt` file not a text message, here is my code:

```
import discord

from discord.ext 

import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.command(pass_context=True)

async def movies(ctx):
    
await ctx.send("Here ya go:")
    
bot.run('***MYTOKEN***')
```

As stated this code is completely functional, what functions must I learn to send the `.txt` files, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

discord.py provides direct support for files

```py
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp, 'new_filename.png'))
```

**Alternatively, if you want to send the contents of the file**

```py
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as fp:
   await ctx.send(fp.read()) # wont work if number of characters is greater than 3000
```

References

1. [Uploading an image](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-upload-an-image)